# Python selenium Can't click button popup

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

i'm unable to click a button on a chrome popup,

This is the button i'm willing to click : "Next" [BUTTON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tktK3.png)

The popup comes up when we click on : Enable the gmail api

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver.get('https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python')
time.sleep(2.5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='button button-primary gc-analytics-event']").click()
time.sleep(2.5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='md-primary hentest-enable-button md-button md-ink-ripple']").click()
```

Comment: which button are you trying to click?  More details are needed

Comment: @JS2775 i added more details

Comment: You can't click on the button, because, GMAIL login form appears, due to webdriver feature, start browser with fresh session, without cookies and stored sessions.

Comment: @Vova i open chrome with cookies, so i'm already logged in . I just cannot click this button because it's on a popup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python')


elem=driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "//a[@class='button button-primary gc-analytics-event']")

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: 'center'})",elem)

elem.click()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 50)

wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(
(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.devsite-henhouse-dialog iframe')))

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, "//button[@class='md-primary hentest-enable-button md-button md-ink-ripple']"))).click()
```

its inside an iframe , switch it to it and use webdriver wait also